# Display error if tFilterRow results == 0

Tags: etl, talend

I have a job in which I use a rowFilter based on a condition. It works. But, what I want to do more is to display an error or stop the job if the number of filtered rows is 0. How can I achieve that?

This is my job:

[image]
Does anyone could help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "`RunIf`" trigger and put the condition that you want here so that the job process would determine it's running course based on it.
On your case it would be something like -

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_OK"))>0
```

`tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_OK` is a global variable part of the `tFilterRow` component which says "Number of lines matching the filter".

If you want to catch the error and print out the details you could connect the "`RunIf`" to `tDie` component and then use `tLogCatcher` component to catch the error - make sure that you have selected the "`Catch tDie`" option.